Integral of $\int_{1-r}^{1+r} \sqrt{(-1 +r -x)(1 - r -x)(1 + r -x)(1 + r + x)} \exp(-x)/x \;dx$
I'd like to find some symbolic result for the integral
$$ \int_{1-r}^{1+r}  \sqrt{(-1 +r -x)(1 - r -x)(1 + r -x)(1 + r + x)} \exp(-x)/x \, dx $$
where $0 < r < 1$.
This integrand comes from the height $a$ of a circle-circle intersection where the two circles have radii 1 and $r$, times an exponential decay factor. $x$ is the distance between the centers of the two circles.
I've tried both Mathematica and Sympy but with no luck. I'd be happy even with a Meijer-G function or similar.

I don't see how to approach the general integral (maybe as a contour integral with a dogbone countour, but it looks unpleasant). At least in the limiting case $r = 1$, we get $\pi (I_1(2) - L_1(2))$, where $I_\bullet$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and $L_\bullet$ is the modified Struve function.

@TravisWillse I'm not currently skilled in contour integration but I agree it would be difficult here. I'd be pretty happy with a series approach, like what Masd proposed below. As another case of r<<1, the value becomes $\pi r^2 \exp(-1)$; this is within a few % even at r=0.5.

Partial answer
Let us write
$$ \sqrt{(-1 +r -x)(1 - r -x)(1 + r -x)(1 + r + x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,(x-1)^n$$ It seems that we have
$$a_{n+4}=\frac{2 (2 n+5) r^2 a_{n+3}+2 (n+1) \left(r^2-2\right)a_{n+2}-2(2n-1)a_{n+1}-(n-2)a_{n}}{(n+4) (r-2) r^2 (r+2) }$$where
$$a_0=r \sqrt{4-r^2}\quad a_1=\frac{2 r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\quad a_2=-\frac{r^4-4 r^2+8}{r \left(4-r^2\right)^{3/2}}  \quad a_3= \frac{8 \left(r^2-2\right)}{r \left(4-r^2\right)^{5/2}}$$
So, we are left with
$$I_n=\int_{1-r}^{1+r} \frac{(x-1)^n}x\,e^{-x}\,dx$$
$$I_n=(-1)^n \big(\text{Ei}(-r-1)-\text{Ei}(r-1)\big)+\frac 2e \big(-r P_n\,\cosh(r)+Q_n\,\sinh(r) \big)$$ where the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & P_n & Q_n \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & 1 & r^2+2 \\
 4 &  r^2+5 & 2r^2+4 \\
 5 &  3 r^2+19 & r^4+10 r^2+20 \\
 6 &  r^4+17 r^2+101 & 4 r^4+50 r^2+100   \\
 7 &  5 r^4+103 r^2+619 & r^6+26 r^4+310 r^2+620 \\
 8 &  r^6+37 r^4+737 r^2+4421 & 6 r^6+184 r^4+2210 r^2+4420 \\
 9 &  7 r^6+299 r^4+5983 r^2+35899 & r^8+50 r^6+1496 r^4+17950   r^2+35900 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
The problem is that I do not know what are these polynomials but they are easy to generate.
Using only the terms given in the above table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
r & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0.05 & 0.00286 & 0.00289 \\
 0.10 & 0.01173 & 0.01159 \\
 0.15 & 0.02648 & 0.02615 \\
 0.20 & 0.04729 & 0.04669 \\
 0.25 & 0.07433 & 0.07338 \\
 0.30 & 0.10782 & 0.10640 \\
 0.35 & 0.14804 & 0.14602 \\
 0.40 & 0.19531 & 0.19255 \\
 0.45 & 0.25004 & 0.24636 \\
 0.50 & 0.31272 & 0.30791 \\
 0.55 & 0.38391 & 0.37770 \\
 0.60 & 0.46429 & 0.45635 \\
 0.65 & 0.55465 & 0.54458 \\
 0.70 & 0.65595 & 0.64323 \\
 0.75 & 0.76934 & 0.75331 \\
 0.80 & 0.89619 & 0.87602 \\
 0.85 & 1.03821 & 1.01287 \\
 0.90 & 1.19739 & 1.16579 \\
 0.95 & 1.37623 & 1.33749 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Not very fantastic yet.

I think this could be a good approach. Perhaps I should have put this in my question, but I'm really interested in an integral with $\exp(-x/\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is some decay length.

^ I'd be interested to know how you did the integral $I_n$; I think the approach will generalize.

@JacobSchwartz. It is pretty trivial since it is sure that the exponential integrals appear. Then, "looking" for a pattern (I am blind) and blabla ! I did do it with $\exp(-x/\lambda)$ : it looks very similar. By the way, if you consider that this is possible way to go, may be, you accept it as an answer in order other members of our community know it. Cheers

This is just a start, but the coefficients of unity for $P_n$: 0,1,1,5,19,101,619 are alternating factorials, OEIS A005165. I haven't yet found a series for the r^2 terms.
